# RecyclerView does not show all items inside BottomSheetDialogFragment

Tags: android

I have BottomSheetDialogFragment with an input field and RecyclerView. ConstraintLayout has height set at match_parent and RecylcerView's height is 0dp.

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="android.support.design.widget.BottomSheetBehavior">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_enter_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
        android:hint="Enter a city"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="Autofill,TextFields" />


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rv_result"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/et_enter_text"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**The problem** is that RecyclerView shows just 6 of 9 elements when the keyboard is open.

The keyboard is overlapping RecyclerView even when android:windowSoftInputMode is set to adjustResize. Desired behavior is to make RecyclerView bottom constraint attached to the top of the keyboard.

[See screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hCYg.png)

This is style for bottom sheet.

```html
<style name="AppBottomSheetDialogTheme"
      parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
      <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustResize</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be quick similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47718181/4334526) issue.

Adding

```
app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
```

to the RecyclerView like it was suggested in [[1]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65124563/4334526) [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67834578/4334526) did work for me

Comment: This is should be the correct and accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

Change `ConstraintLayout` to `LinearLayout`. I had the same problem, which got resolved by this method.

Answer (score 4):

Please use LinearLayout instead of constraint layout because sometimes expected weird behavior when recycler view inside constraint layout

Something like this

```
<LinearLayout>
   ....
   <RecyclerView/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 4):

use this property

```
app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
```

in your recycler view like this:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_filter_sections"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/button_filter_confirm"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHeight_default="wrap"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/text_view_filter_title"
        tools:itemCount="500"
        tools:listitem="@layout/list_item_financial_filter" />
```